# In iOS Safari, how do you disable a html button element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, forms

I've discovered that my iPad (iOS 7) doesn't disable `<button>` elements even when they have the `disabled` attribute on them.  They are disabled on every other browser I've tried on my OS (Windows 7): FF, Chrome, Safari.

If I take the same html and simply replace the `<button>` and with an `<input type="button">`, the input becomes disabled as you'd expect.  The reason I want to keep it as a `<button>` is because I want to put an `img` inside and that doesn't seem to work with an `input`.  So how do you disable `<button>` on iOS Safari?  [Here is a jsfiddle that can reproduce this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/zHmWw/1/):

```
<div id="hero-1" class="hero">
    <button disabled="" class="go-to-hero">
        <div style="background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-oWvCrkzPjX9VBkJavc48RfBP1mSLPYMUIe8FpSaNzpgWWEL55A');background-position: -399px -42px;width: 13px;height: 15px">
        </div>
    </button>
</div>

<div id="hero-2" class="hero">
    <input type="button" disabled="" class="go-to-hero">
        <div style="background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-oWvCrkzPjX9VBkJavc48RfBP1mSLPYMUIe8FpSaNzpgWWEL55A');background-position: -399px -42px;width: 13px;height: 15px">
        </div>
    </input>
</div>
```

When I view this in my iPad, the first button is enabled and the second is disabled. I want them to both be disabled.

Comment: The correct way to disable a button in XHTML is to use it like that : `disabled='disabled'`. If your files is an XHTML, that may be the problem.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon when it's `disabled="disabled"`, it has the same issue.

Comment: I am also interested in this; was this ever resolved, as it still happens!